# How to pass Json for display in Bootsfaces table

Tags: java, json, list, bootsfaces

I have a json of below format -

```
{"name":"abc","id":"101","age":"22"}
```

I want to display this json in Bootsfaces Table with **key** as one column and **values** as other column.

My approach is to convert this **json** to **List** (Keys in one list and Values in another list)and then pass to 2 different columns in Table.

ListOfKeys    - [name , id , age]

ListOfValues  - [abc , 101 , 22]

But I am not finding any easy approach to display these lists to Table in separate columns.

**Can anyone please suggest programmatically..how to convert List to Bootsfaces Table**

**or any other easy approach for converting json to Table?**

I am just a beginner.Any help would be appreciated.Thankyou.

Comment: I suggest you to convert your JSON to POJO first..Are you doing that??

Comment: No.. But Can you please explain programmatically how to do that?

Comment: I doubt converting the Json to a POJO makes things simpler :). Quite the contrary. You'd need the reflection API to iterate the variables of the POJO. If the question is to create a table consisting of a "keys" and "values" column, that is.

Answer (score 0):

Create an object containing both key and value:

```
public class Row {
  private String key;
  private String value;
  // plus getters and setters (omitted for brevity)
}
```

and pass an array of these objects to the datatable:

```
public class MyBean {
  private List<Row> table = new ArrayList<>();
  // plus getter and setter
  public MyBean(String json) {
    // parse Json and populate the table array with it
    // (omitted for brevity)
  }
}


<b:dataTable value="#{myBean.table}" var="row">
  <b:dataTableColumn value="#{row.key}" />
  <b:dataTableColumn value="#{row.value}" />
</b:dataTable>
```